# I want to use an out parameter with string variable

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use an out parameter with string variable.

For Example:

```
string Url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier"

string BaseUrl = this.DecompositionUrl(out Url).BaseUrl;
string ServiceUrl = this.DecompositioUrl(out Url).ServiceUrl;
```

I want to using a method like this.

```
 public static string DecompositionUrl(out string Urlr)
    {
        // enter here  :
        BaseUrl = Urlr.Substring(0,40);
        ServiceUrl = Urlr.Substring(40,Urlr.Length);
    }
```

When returned my `DecompositionUrl` I want to set `BaseUrl` and `ServiceUrl`

Comment: You should change your `out` parameter to be a custom class with a `BaseUrl` and `ServiceUrl` property.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare `out` parameters for the two values that you intend to return from your method: `baseUrl` and `serviceUrl`. The source `url` needs to be passed in through an ordinary parameter (not `out`).

```
public static void DecompositionUrl(string url, out string baseUrl, out string serviceUrl)
{
    baseUrl = url.Substring(0, 40);
    serviceUrl = url.Substring(40);
}
```

You would then call your method like so:

```
string url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier"
DecompositionUrl(url, out var baseUrl, our var serviceUrl);
Console.WriteLine($"Base URL is {baseUrl} and service URL is {serviceUrl}.");
```

Answer (score 3):

C# 7 allows you to return a 'tuple' as the result of a method like this

```
   public static (string, string) DecompositionUrl(string url)
    {
        var baseUrl = ...;
        var serviceUrl = ...;
        return (baseUrl, serviceUrl);
    }
```

You can then use it like this

```
(string baseUrl, string serviceUrl) = DecompositionUrl("https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier");
```

I think that's better than using the `out` keyword since it's clearer what's input and what's output.